# Creating an interactive "movie" from a Microsoft PowerPoint 2003 presentation (.ppt file) containing animation

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

I have created a Microsoft PowerPoint 2003 presentation (a **.ppt** file) on Windows XP that contains a lot of animation, using PowerPoint's Custom Animation tools.  I would like to share this presentation -- animations and all -- with a colleague who has a Mac computer and does not have PowerPoint or Keynote.  Is it possible to make a "movie" from my **.ppt** file that contains a lot of animation?

I recall that another colleague once made me a QuickTime "movie" from a PowerPoint file, I think (although I do not remember whether he made it using Windows or Mac).  On this "movie," clicking advanced the animation/slide, just as clicking would do in an actual PowerPoint presentation.  In that sense, it was not really strictly a movie, since I could interact with it by clicking.

Do you know how to make such an interactive "movie" from a PowerPoint 2003 presentation (a **.ppt** file)?  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Would using another piece of software on the Mac solve the problem? Or would you rather make a movie of the full presentation?

Comment: @N_Lindz I would rather make a movie of the full presentation. Thanks!

Comment: why not use a screen capture software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are heaps of products around that pretend to be able to convert a presentation
to video while conserving animations. However, you will never know if they can succeed
on *your presentation* without trying them out, but luckily trial versions are ususally available,

Here is a quick and unverified list of some of them :

- Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 can save a presentation as video. For details see [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-HA010336763.aspx).
  If you don't have this version, maybe you know someone that can do you this service for free.
- [Leawo PowerPoint to Video](http://www.leawo.com/powerpoint-video-converter/) (free and pro versions, pro at $44.95, mostly good [reviews](http://download.cnet.com/Leawo-PowerPoint-to-Video-Pro/3000-2075_4-10906808.html))
- [Acoolsoft PPT to Video](http://www.acoolsoft.com/powerpoint-to-video-overview.html#105) ($49.95, good [reviews](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Encoders-Converter-DIVX-Related/Acoolsoft-PPT-to-Video-Free.shtml))
- [Presentation to Video Converter](http://www.geovid.com/Presentation_to_Video_Converter/) ($59.95, negative [reviews](http://download.cnet.com/Presentation-to-Video-Converter/3000-2194_4-10363146.html))
- [PowerPoint to Video](http://www.hexisoft.com/) ($39.95)

Comment: +1 for harry but just to add to this answer... I've used CamStudio in the past with good results.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a good screen recorder, such as **CamStudio**.
2. Open the PowerPoint file.
3. Record the entire file with the screen recorder. (If you have trouble doing this, consult the forums.)
4. Then save the file in **AVI** format.
5. Send the **AVI** file to your friend by attaching it to an email message.